# R count() using dynamically generated list of variables/columns

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

If I have a tibble called `observations` with the following variables/columns:

```
category_1_red_length
category_1_red_width
category_1_red_depth
category_1_blue_length
category_1_blue_width
category_1_blue_depth
category_1_green_length
category_1_green_width
category_1_green_depth
category_2_red_length
category_2_red_width
category_2_red_depth
category_2_blue_length
category_2_blue_width
category_2_blue_depth
category_2_green_length
category_2_green_width
category_2_green_depth
```

Plus a load more. Is there a way to dynamically generate the following `count()`?

```
count(observations, 
  category_1_red_length,
  category_1_red_width,
  category_1_red_depth,
  category_1_blue_length,
  category_1_blue_width,
  category_1_blue_depth,
  category_1_green_length,
  category_1_green_width,
  category_1_green_depth,
  category_2_red_length,
  category_2_red_width,
  category_2_red_depth,
  category_2_blue_length,
  category_2_blue_width,
  category_2_blue_depth,
  category_2_green_length,
  category_2_green_width,
  category_2_green_depth,
  sort=TRUE)
```

I can create the list of columns I want to count with:

```
columns_to_count = list()
column_prefix = 'category'
aspects = c('red', 'blue', 'green')
dimensions = c('length', 'width', 'depth')
for (x in 1:2) {
  for (aspect in aspects) {
    for (dimension in dimensions) {
    columns_to_count = append(columns_to_count, paste(column_prefix, x, aspect, dimension, sep='_'))
    }
  }
}
```

But then how do I pass my list of columns in `columns_to_count` to the `count()` function?

In my actual data set there are about 170 columns like this that I want to count so creating the list of columns without loops doesn't seem sensible.

Struggling to think of the name for what I'm trying to do so unable to find useful search results.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use non-standard evaluation using `syms` and `!!!`. For example, using `mtcars` dataset

```
library(dplyr)
library(rlang)

cols <- c('am', 'cyl')
mtcars %>% count(!!!syms(cols), sort = TRUE)

#  am cyl  n
#1  0   8 12
#2  1   4  8
#3  0   6  4
#4  0   4  3
#5  1   6  3
#6  1   8  2
```

This is same as doing

```
mtcars %>% count(am, cyl, sort = TRUE)

#  am cyl  n
#1  0   8 12
#2  1   4  8
#3  0   6  4
#4  0   4  3
#5  1   6  3
#6  1   8  2
```

You don't need to include names in `cols` one by one by hand. You can use regex if the column contains a specific pattern or use position to get appropriate column name.

Comment: Yes in hindsight regex would be a good way to do for this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.dots` to receive strings as variables:

```r
count(observations, .dots=columns_to_count, sort=TRUE)
```

```r
r$> d 
  V1 V2
1  1  4
2  2  5
3  3  6

r$> count(d, .dots=list('V1', 'V2'))  
# A tibble: 3 x 3
     V1    V2     n
  <int> <int> <int>
1     1     4     1
2     2     5     1
3     3     6     1

r$> count(d, V1, V2)   
# A tibble: 3 x 3
     V1    V2     n
  <int> <int> <int>
1     1     4     1
2     2     5     1
3     3     6     1
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work as ```columns_to_count``` is a list of strings. I think the ```do.call``` in your example is the same as:

```count(observations, 
  'category_1_red_length',
  'category_1_red_width',
  'category_1_red_depth',
  ...,
  'category_2_green_depth',
  sort=TRUE)```

I need to convert the string column names to references to the columns in observations?